# gridview sorting: need to re-read every time?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm populating a GridView with code, setting datasource to the dataset returned by a query. So apparently sorting and paging don't just work magically like if I use a datasourceid= some sqldatasource.

I've found a number of examples of how to do this on the web, but they all appear to re-execute the query every time. Shouldn't the contents of the query be saved in the view state? Is there some way to just get the previous query results and re-sort without having to go back to the database? (Is it saving all the data in the view state? If so, why can't I get to it? It seems pretty dumb to send it all to the user's browser and send it all back, wasting all the bandwidth, if there's no way to get to it.)

Also, if I try to allow paging, it appears I again have to re-execute the query every time the user goes to another page. And if the user sorts and then pages, then I have to remember what the sort order was in a hidden field or some such, so I can re-read the data, re-sort, and then go to the right page.

Given that when you use a data source control all this behavior is built in, I think I'm missing something here. But given all the examples out there that do it this slow, hard way, if I'm missing something, a lot of other programmers are missing it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an ASP.NET GridView control every time you sort a column or page through the data set then you're making a server postback. Sorting and paging with this particular control has never worked 'magically' and has long been a bugbear of mine.

You can speed things up by storing the data source that you're building the grid from in memory, either as a session or through the ViewState. Both have pros and cons and I suggest you read up.

If at all possible I suggest forgetting the ASP.NET GridView and looking at a client side solution such as the jQuery jqGrid. It uses AJAX calls to sort and page and is much, much faster and less of a headache. The only drawback is the learning curve but believe me it's worth it in the long run.

Comment: By "sorked magically" I meant that if you use a data source control, you don't have to write any code to implement paging or sorting. You geta all that for free.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use session data, but I really dislike the idea for something like this: there's no reliable way to discard the data when it's no longer needed, and so it ends up floating around forever, and you run into issues if the user can have two instances of the screen open at the same time. Saving in the viewstate is possible but doubles the bandwidth. The time to read the data coming back in over the wire would be more than what it would take to requery the database in many, maybe most, cases. So sure it's do-able, but it's not pretty.

Comment: OK I see what you're saying... personally I hate using data source controls because it abstracts too much of what is going on under the hood but it does save a lot of time. ViewState isn't ideal, session is probably the way to go if you can invest some time in making the data discard more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the gridview re-execute the query every time.

If the query takes too long, you can manually store data in the session, or ViewState. And in the Algorithm that populates the grid just read them directly for it, instead of running the query.

you can, in the page load event, run the query one time when there is no postback (you can check for postback with

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
    //Run the query and save it to the session
}
```

and the the method that populate the grid, should read from the session directly. no need to run the query again